# ¿Como puedo llamar a a una función javascript desde php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo un archivo php en el que quiero llamar a una función que tengo en un archivo javascript, el problema es que la mayoría de ejemplos que encuentro son con jQuery o con scripts dentro del mismo archivo

Comment: Es necesario que seas más especifico en tu pregunta. Por lo pronto lo que te puedo decir es que javascript no lo llamas desde php, sino que se invoca desde html con la etiqueta <script></script>.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr dar una respuesta valida a tu pregunta, es necesario tener en contexto diferentes aspectos de la comunicación básica que se lleva al cabo en un arquitectura de tipo cliente servidor y la ejecución secuencial de programas desde una forma general.

### Contexto

Vamos a tratar al equipo computacional que hace las veces de servidor como maquina servidor, y al programa servidor como servidor web.

Suponiendo que estas haciendo uso de un servidor web del tipo apache httpd o nginx, debes entender que cuando la maquina servidor recibe una petición al puerto de escucha que tienes abierto apuntando a tu servidor web, este lo direcciona al software encargado, en este punto el servidor web intentara buscar el recurso que intentar alcanzar, si lo encuentra entonces evalúa que tipo de recurso es, es este caso un archivo php, entonces intentara buscar el handler que hace referencia a los ficheros del tipo php, el cual naturalmente es el interprete del lenguaje, el archivo es parseado, evaluado y ejecutado por el interprete de php dándole como respuesta un archivo limpio html con el código php ya resuelto al servidor web, el cual lo retornara en la respuesta a la petición inicial.

Posteriormente, cuando el cliente (posiblemente navegador web) obtiene el fichero con contenido html, este continua con su proceso de critical rendering path de forma normal, dentro de este proceso se lleva a cabo el fetch de archivos js si es necesario, y se ejecutan.

### Respuestas

#### Respuesta 1

Ahora bien, si en la ejecución de js que indicas que requieres hacer desde php, debe retornar datos de js hacia php, no es tan sencillo como creo que lo piensas actualmente, debes hacer uso de comunicación asincrona por medio de un XMLHttpRequest, ajax de jquery, axios, fetch u otro, de forma tal que crees un endpoint php que reciba los datos y te retorne lo que desees a js de nuevo.

#### Respuesta 2

Si lo que quieres es que simplemente se lleve al cabo una operación desde js cuando la pagina cargue sin que esta dependa de datos consultados por código php, entonces debes quitar a php de esta parte del algoritmo, simplemente colocando "quemado" el código en el archivo php dentro de un tag `<script>` es suficiente, claro debes tener en cuenta que si debes manipular el DOM, este algo ya debe estar cargado.

Answer (score 0):

En cualquier parte del código php la puedes abrir con el mismo javascript:

`?><script>NombreFuncion();</script><?php`

Suerte.